# Comparing horizental cells with vertical cells on excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have a excel sheet[image]

and i want to compare the value on the cells in vertical with the cells in horizental and put an "X" on the interaction

this is what i did :

```
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harnwire")
For j = 2 To 100 Step 1
For i = 2 To 900 Step 1
If c.Cells(i, 1).Value = c.Cells(1, j).Value Then

c.Cells(i, j).Value = "X"
Else
c.Cells(i, j).Value = " "
```

Comment: It is not clear which column has the header in the column. You can not tell where the rows are located. As shown in the example, it is clear that the contents of the columns and rows are constant or mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
If c.Cells(i, 1).Value = c.Cells(1, j).Value Then
```

seems t be incorrect. Because this compares column `A` to the headers in row 1. This line is essentially the same as

```
If c.Cells(i, "A").Value = c.Cells(1, j).Value Then
```

Yet, based on the picture, it seems that you are more interested to compare another column with the header. So, maybe try something like this instead:

```
If c.Cells(i, "G").Value = c.Cells(1, j).Value Then
```

<sub>(or whichever the correct column is)</sub>.

So, bringing it all together that would be:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowNumber As Long, columnNumber As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harnwire")

For columnNumber = 2 To 100
    For rowNumber = 2 To 900
        If c.Cells(rowNumber, "G").Value = c.Cells(1, columnNumber).Value Then
            c.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = "X"
        Else
            c.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = vbNullString
        End If
    Next rowNumber
Next columnNumber

End Sub
```

### Update:

The following code addresses the comments provided:
(1) Start comparing with the headers in column `H` and
(2) error handling if the two cells cannot be compared because either cell contains an error.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowNumber As Long, columnNumber As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harnwire")

For columnNumber = 8 To 100
    For rowNumber = 2 To 900
        If IsError(c.Cells(rowNumber, "G").Value) Or IsError(c.Cells(1, columnNumber).Value) Then
            c.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = "err"
        Else
            If c.Cells(rowNumber, "G").Value = c.Cells(1, columnNumber).Value Then
                c.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = "X"
            Else
                c.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next rowNumber
Next columnNumber

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for u respond but still i have a little probleme with the code its give me an error 424 on the line considered to be wrong is the  `If c.Cells(rowNumber, "G").Value = c.Cells(1, columnNumber).Value Then `

Comment: And the comparaison that i want to do is compare a column but no to all the header just starting from " H1"

Comment: If you want to start with column `H` then the line `For columnNumber = 2 To 100` should be `For columnNumber = 8 To 100` (because column `H` is the 8th column / letter).

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear - and sorry but my setup does not allow me
to see pictures uploaded to this site and consequently I can't
see your photo- What your code suggests is that you want to
check 900 rows in column "A" against 100 columns in row 1.
Is that correct.  If there is a match between cell in
column "A" and cell in row 1, then you want the junction
cell between the two to show "X".  Is that correct?

If so, then your logic is correct.  Perhaps your syntax
is off.  Try this.

```
Sub sdftgyhj()

    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("harnwire")
    For j = 2 To 100 Step 1
        For i = 2 To 900 Step 1
            If c.Cells(i, 1).Value = c.Cells(1, j).Value Then
                    c.Cells(i, j).Value = "X"
            Else
                c.Cells(i, j).Value = " "
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```